# How can I modify the parameter of a constructor after it has already been called?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods

Let's say I have this class:

```
public class Customer()
{
private double discountamount;
private double totalPurchase;

public Customer(double tot)
{
this.totalPurchases = tot;

if (tot > 2000.00){setDiscountAmount(0.25);}
else if (tot >= 1000.00){setDiscountAmount(0.15);}
else if (tot >= 500.00){setDiscountAmount(0.10);}
}

public double getDiscountAmount(){return discountAmount;}
public double getTotalPurchases(){return totalPurchases;}

public void setDiscountAmount(double newDiscountAmount){discountAmount = newDiscountAmount;}
public void setTotalPurchases(double newTotalPurchases){totalPurchases = newTotalPurchases;}

}
```

And I want to change the value of the total purchase without creating a new object.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Discounts 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
double totalPurchase;

System.out.print("Enter amount customer has spent: ");
totalPurchase = input.nextDouble();

Customer customer = new Customer(totalPurchase);

System.out.print("\nHas the customer returned with more purchases? ");
boolean loop = input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("yes");
if (loop){
    System.out.print("How many times? ");
    int x = input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        // Accumulate
        System.out.print("Enter amount customer has spent: ");
        totalPurchase += input.nextDouble() * customer.discountAmount;
        customer.setTotalPurchases(totalPurchase);
    }
    System.out.println("Customer Discount Amount: " + customer.discountAmount);
    System.out.println("Customer Total Purchase Amount: " + customer.totalPurchases);
}
}
}
```

But when I print the new discount amount, it remains unchanged. So where am I going wrong and what can I do?

Comment: You never change the discount amount, only the total purchase amount.

Comment: How would I go about changing that discount amount? If the gets and set are there and I moved the logic from the constructor to the ```setTotalPurchases```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `discountAmount` is only set in the constructor, which happens only once an object is instantiated. Instead, you should move the if-statement in your constructor to the `setTotalPurchases`, like so:

```
public class Customer{

    private double discountamount;
    private double totalPurchase;

    public Customer(double tot){
       this.setTotalPurchases(tot);
    }

    public double getDiscountAmount(){return discountAmount;}
    public double getTotalPurchases(){return totalPurchases;}

    public void setDiscountAmount(double newDiscountAmount){discountAmount = newDiscountAmount;}

    public void setTotalPurchases(double newTotalPurchases){
         totalPurchases = newTotalPurchases;
         if (tot > 2000.00){
             setDiscountAmount(0.25);
         }else if (tot >= 1000.00){
             setDiscountAmount(0.15);
         }else if (tot >= 500.00){
             setDiscountAmount(0.10);
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, see, I still don't have the ins and outs of gets and sets. But this clears up a lot about how these work. Thank you.

Comment: Hold on though, now my discount amount is coming out to zero. Could I be calling things wrong in the main or the ```toString```?

Answer (score 2):

You can move the logic for changing the discount amount to a setter:

```
public Customer(double tot) {
    setTotalPurchases(tot);
}

public void setTotalPurchases(double newTotalPurchases){
    totalPurchases = newTotalPurchases;

    if (newTotalPurchases > 2000.00) {
        setDiscountAmount(0.25);
    } else if (newTotalPurchases >= 1000.00) {
        setDiscountAmount(0.15);
    } else if (newTotalPurchases >= 500.00) {
        setDiscountAmount(0.10);
    }
}
```